# HTML: href to local files, using ./ or not

Tags: html

I have two files on the same domain in the same folder:

I am using:

```
<a href="index.html">Link</a>
```

However, I see others using

```
 <a href="./index.html">Link</a>
```

They appear to work the same, what is the difference?

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, is there a code?

Comment: Both are almost same... No difference to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, I made the bits code now.

Comment: @TannerDolby No. `.` refers to the current directory.

Comment: @seventeen Added an exact dupe. Please check.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Ah yes, so as long as `index.html` is in the current directory, the two don't have a difference.

Comment: Going without the `./` will save you 2 bytes, so it is **marginally** better.

Comment: @TannerDolby Yep.